# How to limit api requests by time in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django-rest-framework

There is a specific api endpoint. To reduce the load on the server, I want clients to send post requests to it, for example, no more than once every 15 minutes. At the same time, the rest of the endpoints worked as usual.

I thought that I needed to somehow implement a timeout. So that the client waits and does not receive a response to all requests until 15 minutes have passed. Those. just exit the post function. But it is impossible, it says that you need to return response. But if the client receives a response, he will immediately be able to send the next request. And you need to reduce the number of requests as much as possible. So that this timeout on the client side prevents him from bombing with requests.

And I would like to include the logic for enabling such behavior in the post function. It is a little more complicated than described in the question.

In python and django, a complete noob. Perhaps this can be implemented in some other way? Aim in which direction to dig.

Comment: Have a look if DRF's [`throttling`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/throttling/) can help.

Comment: You can accept my answer if it was the solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Throttling](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/throttling/) and add the following lines to `REST_FRAMEWORK` block of your `settings.py` like below:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ...
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.throttling.AnonRateThrottle',
        'rest_framework.throttling.UserRateThrottle'
    ],
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES': {
        'anon': '20/min',
        'user': '60/min'
    },
    ...
}
```

This will `raise` the `429 status_code` if user send more than 60 requests in one minute.

Answer (score 1):

Throttling can be a solution?

It can set up the rate of request: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/throttling/

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.